# Package versioning policy - Harmless type changes?

Tags: haskell, cabal

The [package versioning policy](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Package_versioning_policy) specifies that changing the type of any entity makes a change of the *B* number in *A.B.C* necessary.

However, it seems to me that some type changes don't break dependent code. In particular, consider the following example, where I drop a `Typeable` class constraint:

```
- foo :: Typeable a => AddHandler a -> NetworkDescription (Event a)
+ foo :: AddHandler a -> NetworkDescription (Event a)
```

So, my question is:

> Can removing a type class constraint on a function break dependent code? Should I change the *B* number or just the *C* in version *A.B.C* when introducing this change?

Comment: I'm not certain SO is a good fit for this question because I don't think there's an authoritatively correct answer other than "whatever The Haskell Community wants".  Maybe do a straw poll on haskell-cafe?  IMHO a minor change would be sufficient.

Comment: @John L: Ok, I will poll on haskell-cafe.

Comment: Seems to me that a tool which could compare two versions of a module and give a definitive answer might be useful.

Comment: @PaulJohnson While I agree, you might wonder whether the "authoritative" answer that tool gave to this question was actually authoritative, or merely oversight on the parts of the people writing the policy/tool. I think that's the core of the question: the policy is clear, but does it actually reflect what people want?

Comment: Some care does need to be taken around defaulting. For example, removing a `Fractional` constraint might cause a type variable that was previously defaulted to `Double` to be defaulted to `Integer` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have replied on -cafe, but I’ll also put my answer here:

You should bump the C number. The [PVP](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Package_versioning_policy#Version_numbers), rule 2, specifies that an API addition implies that the C part of the version is to be increased. Removing a constraint behaves like adding a new function: Code that worked before continues to work, but code written against the new API might not work against the old one.

So if a programmer develops code against version 0.1.2 of foo, he’d specify `foo >= 0.1.2 && < 0.2` as the requirement. He does not expect his code to work against foo-0.1.1. This works fine with removing the constraint.

Comment: As a developer, I would never add a C level constraint to a package description until someone complained that it was broken without it.

Comment: @Joachim Breitner: Agreed, thanks. Furthermore, removing constraints should not create any ambiguity issues (since contexts get removed), though UndecidableInstances might spoil the fun.

Answer (score 2):

> Can removing a type class constraint on a function break dependent code?

**No**, I don't believe so. Here's my reasoning. It's common to think of constraints as an additional function argument: a typeclass dictionary which is passed implicitly. You can think slightly more general than that, and imagine that constraints are a record of *evidences* which is passed implicitly. Thus, the type `Foo` can be thought of as `{} -> Foo`, where `{}` indicates an empty record of implicit evidences. It is irrelevant whether `Foo` itself is a function or not.

Now, suppose that our API promises to deliver something of type

```
{SomeConstraint} -> Foo
```

But what we actually deliver is

```
{} -> Foo
```

Well, record subtyping tells us that

```
{SomeConstraint} <: {}
```

therefore function subtyping tells us that

```
({} -> Foo) <: ({SomeConstraint} -> Foo)
```

therefore, anywhere in someone's program that we find a hole with the shape `{SomeConstraint} -> Foo`, we can plug in a `{} -> Foo`. In other words, nothing breaks. The user gives us evidence that `SomeConstraint` is satisfied, and we just ignore it.

---

At first I thought that weird corner cases in type inference might cause problems, but I cannot think of any examples where this is actually the case. So this thought was proven wrong by exhaustion of imagination.